# Permission denied error with RVM

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rvm

I have searched for this problem and couldn't find relevant similar questions. Please bear with me if this is repetitive.

I have followed guides in [RVM](http://rvm.beginrescueend.com/rvm/install/) website to install RVM and I have installed rubies:

```
syed@rails:~$ rvm list

rvm rubies

   ruby-1.8.7-p302 [ i386 ]
=> ruby-1.9.2-p0 [ i386 ]
```

As you can see I have made ruby-1.9.2 my default.

This is my gem directory:

```
syed@rails:~$ rvm gemdir
/home/syed/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p0
```

Now, I tried to install rails and I am thrown the following error:

```
syed@rails:~$ gem install rails
ERROR:  While executing gem ... (Errno::EACCES)
    Permission denied - /home/syed/.gem/specs
```

I even did this without making any difference to the error:

```
syed@rails:~$ chown -R syed /home/syed/.rvm/
```

Currently, my environment looks like this:

```
syed@rails:~$ gem environment
RubyGems Environment:
  - RUBYGEMS VERSION: 1.3.7
  - RUBY VERSION: 1.9.2 (2010-08-18 patchlevel 0) [i686-linux]
  - INSTALLATION DIRECTORY: /home/syed/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p0@rails3
  - RUBY EXECUTABLE: /home/syed/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.2-p0/bin/ruby
  - EXECUTABLE DIRECTORY: /home/syed/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p0@rails3/bin
  - RUBYGEMS PLATFORMS:
    - ruby
    - x86-linux
  - GEM PATHS:
     - /home/syed/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p0@rails3
     - /home/syed/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p0@global
  - GEM CONFIGURATION:
     - :update_sources => true
     - :verbose => true
     - :benchmark => false
     - :backtrace => false
     - :bulk_threshold => 1000
  - REMOTE SOURCES:
     - http://rubygems.org/
```

I don't understand why it is trying to install gems to my system gem directory path?

Comment: Also found a weird thing happening now. When I open a new shell, the ruby version should be the one which is installed system-wide (i.e., ruby-1.8.7) isn't it? But, it is giving me 1.9.2 and I have to do rvm system to come back to that.

Comment: Very oddd. Try `chmod -R u+w /home/syed/.rvm`

Answer (score 18, accepted):

I had this same problem and I resolved it by doing the following:

```
sudo mkdir ~/.gem/specs
sudo chmod 777 ~/.gem/specs
```

It seems that RVM was trying to create this "specs" folder, but didn't have permissions to do so.

Comment: Should a modification request be submitted to deal with this?  Very confusing for beginners and no mention of this problem in current tutorials.

Comment: It's a very bad idea to use chmod 777 for this purpose. Use `chown` instead.

Comment: This maybe you previously installed rubygems, I tried to removed $HOME/.gem directory, and it also works.

Answer (score 5):

I really don't like the accepted answer, its a hack not a solution suitable for production. When you chmod 777 you are giving anyone on the machine access complete access to those folders.

It is much better to create a individual gemset for that project then make sure you own it with chown.

```
rvm gemset create project
rvm use ruby-1.9.3-p394@project # May not be necessary
```

And in your gems folder, for the case above "home/syed/.rvm/gems/" make sure the new gemset you created is owned by you

```
cd home/syed/.rvm/gems/ && ls -la
```

If you don't own it then chown it to your user

```
sudo chown -R user:rvm gemset
```

Answer (score 3):

Maybe try to check also the "`chown`" permissions for the necessary files/directories to find out more about your error message.

Usually I create gemset for the different applications/projects so I don't get a mixture of hundreds of different gems at one place after few weeks/months. Try this:

```
rvm use 1.9.2
rvm gemset create YOURGEMSETNAME
rvm gemset use YOURGEMSETNAME
```

or simply

```
rvm 1.9.2@YOURGEMSETNAME --create
```

Try to install your gems after that. If your want the gems appear for every gemset for ruby 1.9.2, than switch to the *global* gemset and install your gems there:

```
rvm 1.9.2@global
gem install rails3 # or whatever you wish
```

Comment: I tried this earlier: $ rvm use --create 1.9.2@rails3
But, it is throwing up same errors. It is taking /home/syed/.gem/specs as the gem directory instead of /home/syed/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p0@rails3. I don't know why.

Comment: That's strange, it is supposed to work without any permission problems. Check your permissions thoroughly again..

Answer (score 2):

I solved this one, finally. It turns out that my firewall was blocking 199.91.171.93. When I opened access, I no longer got `Errno::EACCES` messages. I diagnosed this by using --verbose and I could see the source was trying to update the $HOME/.gem/specs/rubygems.org%80/quick/Marshal.4.8 area, but could not simply because the traffic was blocked.

Answer (score 2):

I just had this problem and wanted to record my answer for posterity.  All of the directories in my Ruby-specific RVM directory were owned by root.  So I had to chown all of them.

```
~/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p286

drwxr-xr-x  22 root           staff   748 Nov 12 13:34 bin
drwxr-xr-x   2 root           staff    68 Nov 20 14:42 cache
drwxr-xr-x   2 root           staff    68 Nov  1 09:59 doc
drwxr-xr-x  47 root           staff  1598 Nov 12 13:34 gems
```

I don't know if this is normal but after changing them all to my non-root user the problem went away.

Answer (score 1):

What's your path look like?  It sounds like you're getting a system version of gem instead of the rvm-based command.

Comment: My path:
/home/syed/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p0/bin:/home/syed/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p0@global/bin:/home/syed/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.2-p0/bin:/home/syed/.rvm/bin:/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/sbin:/bin:/usr/games

Answer (score 1):

For those coming from Google: On Windows I had this problem because I had an older version of Ruby installed in my `Program Files` directory, which newer versions of Windows have security restrictions on. Run `ruby --version` to make sure it is as expected.